# HOW - to convert a python generator to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, generator, python-3.7

Im very new to python and pandas dataframe and im struggling to wrap my head around how to convert a python generator to a pandas dataframe.

What i want to do is to fetch a large table into chunks with this function that yields a generator:

```
def fetch_data_into_chunks(cursor, arraysize=10**5):
    while True:
        results = cursor.fetchmany(arraysize)
        if not results:
            break
        for result in results:
            yield result
```

Then i want to append or concat the result to a pandas dataframe:

```
for data in fetch_data_into_chunks(cursor):
    df.append(data)
```

But this doesnt works and give me the error message:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'pyodbc.Row'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a connection to a sql database, you can use Pandas's built-in `read_sql` method and specify a chunksize. This is in itself a generator, which you can iterate through to create a single dataframe.

In this example, `sql` is your sql query and `conn` is the connection to your database.

```
def fetch_data(sql, chunksize=10**5):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    reader = pd.read_sql(sql,
                         conn,
                         chunksize=chunksize)
    for chunk in reader:
        df = pd.concat([df, chunk], ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can i convert this to be asynchronous using asyncio?
`df = pd.concat(
            [chunk for chunk in
                pd.read_sql(query,
                            con=CACHE,
                            chunksize=10**5)])`

Comment: No, I'm not familiar, sorry.